# Fetching the accepted header from a REST API

Tags: rest

In the context of **REST API**, for instance, the `Allow` [header response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses) field is useful to fetch:
*Valid actions for a specified resource*.

Example:

```
Allow: GET, HEAD
```

Is there also a well-know field in order to get a list of accepted *Accept header*? something such as:

```
Accept: application/vnd.company.api.com.foo+json;v=42, application/vnd.company.api.com.foo+xml;v=42
```

Comment: Do you really need to auto-discover this information? Generally, supported media types would be out-of-band information, and in your case (since you're using presumably unregistered media types), it would *definitely* be out-of-band information.

Comment: I agree because, in the given example, `foo` wasn't an hypermedia type.
The capacity to auto-discover this information may however be useful for the long term, where an API (without any version) may first use HAL, before to switch to Siren 2 years later...
I think it would be dangerous and difficult to anticipe too much and by deciding to use a particular hypermedia language for all the life of an API. Tomorrow is another day.

Comment: Right. By using the root menu option as a place to advertise what media types it supports, not only can the server advertise which media types it supports but can also do so at a more fine-grained level (because you could vary supported media types per linked resource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to the client to tell the service what it can accept, because there isn't a whole lot the client can do if it can't accept a response (as it wouldn't know how to handle the returned media type).

If the server isn't capable of creating a resource representation that conforms, it can do one of two things:

- send a 406 Not Acceptable
- send a response which does not conform to the Accept header (HTTP 1.1)

If the server sends a 406, according to [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), as long as it isn't a HEAD request, "the response SHOULD include an entity containing a list of available entity characteristics and location(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate. The entity format is specified by the media type given in the Content-Type header field."

In plain English, this means the response should be accompanied by links to content which it *can* provide. The media type can be communicated by attaching a *profile* attribute to the included links (though this varies by media type).

One way to learn what kind of media types a server provides is to discover them through a menu of links provided at the root URI (using a well-known media type). For example, your request to `/` may specify an accept header of `text/html` and receive the following response:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="foo" type="application/vnd.company.api.com.foo+json;v=42" href="http://v42.api.com/foos/3713678123" />
    <link rel="foo" type="application/vnd.company.api.com.foo+json;v=43" href="http://v43.api.com/foos/3713678123" />
  </head>
</html>
```